# How to correctly aggregate with the field is a list on Elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

Currently the ES logs are indexed in a way that some fields have a list instead of a single value.

For example:

```
_source:{
    "field1":"["item1", "item2", "item3"], 
    "field2":"something", 
    "field3": "something_else"
}
```

Of course, the length of list is not always the same. I'm trying to find a way to aggregate the number of logs that consist each item (so some logs will be counted multiple times)

I know I have to use `aggs`, but how can I form the right query (after `-d`)?

Comment: Can you please share what output do you want in the result?

Comment: @Richa Say I have 3 records: Record1 has {"field1":"["item1", "item2", "item3"], "other-fiends":"other-value"....}, Record2:{"field1":"["item1"], ....}, Record3:{"field1":"["item1", "item2"], ....} Now I want to find a way to aggregate so that result will be something like {"item1": "Record1:{data-from-Record1}, Record2:{data-from-Record2}, Record3:{data-from-Record3}, "item2": Record1, Record3, "item3": Record1}

Answer (score 0):

You can use below query that uses `terms aggregation` and `top_hits`.

```
{
"size": 0, 
"aggs": {
  "group": {
     "terms": {
        "script": "_source.field1.each{}"
     },
     "aggs":{
      "top_hits_log"   :{
       "top_hits"   :{
       }
      }
     }
    }       
   }
 }
```

Output will be:

```
 "buckets": [
        {
           "key": "item1",
           "doc_count": 3,
           "top_hits_log": {
              "hits": {
                 "total": 3,
                 "max_score": 1,
                 "hits": [
                    {
                       "_index": "so",
                       "_type": "test",
                       "_id": "1",
                       "_score": 1,
                       "_source": {
                          "field1": [
                             "item1",
                             "item2",
                             "item3"
                          ],
                          "field2": "something1"
                       }
                    },
                    {
                       "_index": "so",
                       "_type": "test",
                       "_id": "2",
                       "_score": 1,
                       "_source": {
                          "field1": [
                             "item1"
                          ],
                          "field2": "something2"
                       }
                    },
                    {
                       "_index": "so",
                       "_type": "test",
                       "_id": "3",
                       "_score": 1,
                       "_source": {
                          "field1": [
                             "item1",
                             "item2"
                          ],
                          "field2": "something3"
                       }
                    }
                 ]
              }
           }
        },
        {
           "key": "item2",
           "doc_count": 2,
           "top_hits_log": {
              "hits": {
                 "total": 2,
                 "max_score": 1,
                 "hits": [
                    {
                       "_index": "so",
                       "_type": "test",
                       "_id": "1",
                       "_score": 1,
                       "_source": {
                          "field1": [
                             "item1",
                             "item2",
                             "item3"
                          ],
                          "field2": "something1"
                       }
                    },
                    {
                       "_index": "so",
                       "_type": "test",
                       "_id": "3",
                       "_score": 1,
                       "_source": {
                          "field1": [
                             "item1",
                             "item2"
                          ],
                          "field2": "something3"
                       }
                    }
                 ]
              }
           }
        },
        {
           "key": "item3",
           "doc_count": 1,
           "top_hits_log": {
              "hits": {
                 "total": 1,
                 "max_score": 1,
                 "hits": [
                    {
                       "_index": "so",
                       "_type": "test",
                       "_id": "1",
                       "_score": 1,
                       "_source": {
                          "field1": [
                             "item1",
                             "item2",
                             "item3"
                          ],
                          "field2": "something1"
                       }
                    }
                 ]
              }
           }
        }
     ]
```

Make sure to enable `dynamic scripting`. Set `script.disable_dynamic: false`

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

There is no need to use `scripting`. It will be slow especially `_source` parsing. You also need to make sure your `field1` is `not_analyzed` or you will get weird results as `terms aggregation` is performed on unique tokens in Inverted Index.

```
{
  "size": 0,
  "aggs": {
    "unique_items": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "field1",
        "size": 100
      },
      "aggs": {
        "documents": {
          "top_hits": {
            "size": 10
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Here the size is 100 inside `terms aggregation`, change this according to how many unique values you think you have(default is 10).

Hope this helps!